# Multiply Lists of strings in Python but not by scalar

Tags: python, list

I would like to multiply 2 lists of strings in python but not by values. Like this example :

```
elem1 = ['a', 'b']
elem2 = ['c', 'd']
final = magic_function(elem1, elem2)
>> final = [
    ['a','c'],
    ['a','d'],
    ['b','c'],
    ['b','d']
]
```

I tried looking at the numpy package but I can't find anything which is not multiply by scalar

Comment: Typo : `elem2 = ['a', 'b']`?

Comment: You should have a look at `itertools`, not `numpy`.

Comment: Also, you need to understand the term `multiply`

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get the cartesian product of a series of lists?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/533905/get-the-cartesian-product-of-a-series-of-lists)

Comment: Yup, I have edited the typo. I will look at all your solutions tomorrow, thanks for the answers guys !

Answer (score 1):

This can be done with a simple list comprehension `final = [[v1, v2] for v1 in elem1 for v2 in elem2]`.

Answer (score 1):

```
import itertools
list(itertools.product(elem1,elem2))
```

By using itertools you can have the all possible combination of two lists. But it will generate list of tuples.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at  [**`itertools`**](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html)

Assuming

```
elem1 = ['a', 'b']
elem2 = ['c', 'd']
```

Using list comprehension:

```
[(a, b) for a in elem1 for b in elem2]
```

Result: `[[('a', 'c'), ('b', 'd')], [('a', 'd'), ('b', 'c')]]`

Comment: OP's example doesn't look like permutations at all.